# Docker downloaded over 30 ubuntu images

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I typed in my shell docker command

```
docker pull ubuntu
```

Next I typed

```
docker images
```

And saw over 30 ubuntu images.

```
root@packer-virtualbox-iso:/home# docker images
REPOSITORY                              TAG                   IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu                                  vivid                 bd94ae587483        2 weeks ago         131.3 MB
ubuntu                                  15.04                 bd94ae587483        2 weeks ago         131.3 MB
ubuntu                                  vivid-20150427        bd94ae587483        2 weeks ago         131.3 MB
ubuntu                                  utopic-20150427       d191563ad36b        2 weeks ago         194.5 MB
ubuntu                                  14.10                 d191563ad36b        2 weeks ago         194.5 MB
ubuntu                                  utopic                d191563ad36b        2 weeks ago         194.5 MB
ubuntu                                  trusty-20150427       07f8e8c5e660        2 weeks ago         188.3 MB
ubuntu                                  latest                07f8e8c5e660        2 weeks ago         188.3 MB
ubuntu                                  trusty                07f8e8c5e660        2 weeks ago         188.3 MB
ubuntu                                  14.04                 07f8e8c5e660        2 weeks ago         188.3 MB
ubuntu                                  14.04.2               07f8e8c5e660        2 weeks ago         188.3 MB
ubuntu                                  12.04.5               ac6b0eaa3203        2 weeks ago         132.5 MB
ubuntu                                  precise               ac6b0eaa3203        2 weeks ago         132.5 MB
ubuntu                                  12.04                 ac6b0eaa3203        2 weeks ago         132.5 MB
ubuntu                                  precise-20150427      ac6b0eaa3203        2 weeks ago         132.5 MB
ubuntu                                  vivid-20150421        ef8182f3c943        4 weeks ago         131.3 MB
ubuntu                                  utopic-20150418       0b79d1c2df16        4 weeks ago         194.5 MB
ubuntu                                  trusty-20150320       b7cf8f0d9e82        4 weeks ago         188.3 MB
ubuntu                                  precise-20150320      9610cfc68e8d        4 weeks ago         131.9 MB
dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-composer   latest                5b7f5b652c0a        6 weeks ago         258.6 MB
ubuntu                                  vivid-20150319.1      751a7482c0de        8 weeks ago         131.7 MB
ubuntu                                  utopic-20150319       59a878f244f6        8 weeks ago         194.4 MB
ubuntu                                  vivid-20150309        19c8c047d0fe        10 weeks ago        131.5 MB
ubuntu                                  utopic-20150228.11    525b6e4a4cc8        10 weeks ago        194.4 MB
ubuntu                                  trusty-20150228.11    2103b00b3fdf        10 weeks ago        188.3 MB
ubuntu                                  precise-20150228.11   5898adab7134        10 weeks ago        131.8 MB
ubuntu                                  vivid-20150218        2427658c75a1        12 weeks ago        117.5 MB
ubuntu                                  utopic-20150211       78949b1e1cfd        12 weeks ago        194.4 MB
ubuntu                                  trusty-20150218.1     2d24f826cb16        12 weeks ago        188.3 MB
ubuntu                                  precise-20150212      1f80e9ca2ac3        12 weeks ago        131.5 MB
ubuntu                                  14.04.1               5ba9dab47459        3 months ago        188.3 MB
dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-nginx      latest                76b33b0ca245        3 months ago        193.6 MB
dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-phpfpm     latest                bfbb23b41669        3 months ago        318.5 MB
dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-artisan    latest                a42e33f8719e        5 months ago        229.2 MB
dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-data       latest                42d3f5e26286        5 months ago        154.7 MB
ubuntu                                  12.10                 c5881f11ded9        11 months ago       172.2 MB
ubuntu                                  quantal               c5881f11ded9        11 months ago       172.2 MB
ubuntu                                  13.04                 463ff6be4238        11 months ago       169.4 MB
ubuntu                                  raring                463ff6be4238        11 months ago       169.4 MB
ubuntu                                  saucy                 195eb90b5349        11 months ago       184.6 MB
ubuntu                                  13.10                 195eb90b5349        11 months ago       184.6 MB
ubuntu                                  10.04                 3db9c44f4520        13 months ago       183 MB
ubuntu                                  lucid                 3db9c44f4520        13 months ago       183 MB

root@packer-virtualbox-iso:/home# docker version
Client version: 1.1.2
Client API version: 1.13
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): d84a070
Server version: 1.1.2
Server API version: 1.13
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): d84a070
```

I expected only one ubuntu image. Why docker downloaded all of them?

Comment: Depending on what you are doing with docker this is a question for superuser or serverfault, but not for SO, as it's not programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't specify a tag in a pull, you get all tags. This was [changed in 1.3](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/9c08364a412a51c80e8d17ae14f92549dc543e68), and now you will get `latest` if you fail to specify a tag.

In any case, it's probably best to specify a tag, and you say

```
docker pull ubuntu:14.04
```

if you want (e.g.) 14.04.

Also note that some tags are aliases of each other: you can see that `12.04.5`, `precise-20150427`, `12.04`, and `precise` are all the same image.

Comment: Actually it was [commit 9c08364](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/9c08364a412a51c80e8d17ae14f92549dc543e68), which is in v1.3.0 and later. (`git tag --contains 9c08364`)